# Iteration in Javascript doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to iterate markers on a map which comes from an array, but there is no effect and I don't have an error on the console. The map is without a marker.

```
    var queryLat = [];
    var queryLng = [];

    @foreach($estates as $est)
        var result = $.getJSON({
                url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={{$est->address}}&key={{env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API')}}"

            });

        result.done(function(data) {

            queryLat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            queryLng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        });
    @endforeach


    function initMap()
    {
        var options =
            {
                zoom : 11,
                center : {lat:34.652500, lng:135.506302}
            }

        var map  = new
            google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);


        for (var i = 0; i < queryLat.length; i++)
        {
            var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker
            ({
                position: {lat: queryLat[i], lng: queryLng[i]} ,
                map: map
            });
        }

    }
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing anything?